# My brush in texture paint works weird

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, brushes, texture-paint-mode

When i paint on my model, paint brush doesnt work on some areas:
[image]

That area is slightly based on my current camera view:[image]

That even happens if my camera is far away.

I dont have any inverted normals or double vertices and my brush has no textures applied to it.
My uv map doesnt have any overlays.
I tried both increasing and decreasing size of objects in scene, but that doesnt give any result.

That happens to every object in scene.

I searched alot about that problem in internet, but found nothing

Answer (score 0):

One place you might look is the angle of the Normal Falloff, and see if changing that can help you get the paint to go farther along the projection. Otherwise, you could turn off Backface Culling and try using Face Select Masking to fill the entire selection with more certainty.

[image]